# Django Admin dependent DropDown HTML field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have a **Region** and **SubRegion** ForeignKey in the **Country** Model. My **SubRegion** model also has a **Region** ForeignKey for the **Region** Model. I am having a hard time displaying the **SubRegion** dropdown in the Country Model on the basis of the **Region** selected.

What would be the best way to achieve it? It would be great if dropdowns were based on the value of their parent.

**models.py**

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='is active?', default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubRegion(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='is active?', default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Sub Regions'

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Region')
    subregion = models.ForeignKey(SubRegion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Sub Region')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'is_active', 'is_default', 'created_at', 'updated_at', )
    list_filter = ('region', 'subregion', 'is_active', 'is_default', 'created_at', 'updated_at', )
    search_fields = ('name', 'official_name', )
    fieldsets = (
        ('Region Information', {'fields': ('region', 'subregion', )}),
        ('Basic Information', {'fields': ('name', 'official_name', )}),
        ('Codes Information', {'fields': ('cca2', 'ccn3', 'cca3', 'cioc','idd', 'status', )}),
        ('Coordinates', {'fields': ('latitude', 'longitude', )}),
        ('Membership & Statuses', {'fields': (('is_independent', 'is_un_member', 'is_default', 'is_active', ), )}),
        ('Country Flag', {'fields': ('png_flag_url', 'svg_flag_url', )}),
        ('Country Map', {'fields': ('google_map_url', 'openstreet_map_url', )}),
        ('Additional Information', {'fields': ('population', 'area', 'start_of_week', 'postal_code_format', 'postal_code_regex', )}),
    )
    inlines = [CountryTopLevelDomainInline, CountryCurrencyInline, CountryTimezoneInline]


admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
```

Currently, Whenever I am going to add/edit a country then the complete region and subregion are visible on the select dropdown. What I want like possibilities to load the subregion on the basis of region selection.

Comment: You may need JS for this... depending on the value of Region selected, you can populate the options of SubRegion

Comment: What I mean is, search for how to solve your problem in Javascript. Javascript would provide a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long research, I was able to solve this issue.

I have created the JS file inside my application.

**static\geo_location\js\chained-region.js**

```
var response_cache = {};
function get_subregion_for_region(region_id) {
    (function($){
        var selected_value = $("#id_subregion").val();
        if(response_cache[region_id]){
            $("#id_subregion").html(response_cache[region_id]);
            $("select#id_subregion option").each(function(){
                if ($(this).val() == selected_value)
                    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
            });
        } else {
            $.getJSON("/geo-location/get-subregions-for-region", {region_id:region_id}, function(res, textStatus){
                var options = '<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>';
                $.each(res.data, function(i, item){
                    options += '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
                });
                response_cache[region_id] = options;
                $("#id_subregion").html(response_cache[region_id]);
                $("select#id_subregion option").each(function(){
                    if ($(this).val() == selected_value)
                        $(this).attr("selected","selected");
                });
            });
        }
    })(django.jQuery);
}
```

then, added the views function to handle AJAX requests.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import SubRegion


@login_required
def subregion_for_region(request):
    if 'region_id' in request.GET and request.GET['region_id'] != '':
        subregions = SubRegion.objects.filter(region=request.GET['region_id'])
        return JsonResponse({'data': [{'id': subregion.id, 'name': subregion.name} for subregion in subregions]})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'data': []})
```

**Note:-** I have added the @login_required decorator to prevent the unnecessary call.

And, in the **admin.py** I have created the form and added the "onchange" event on the region dropdown.

**admin.py**

```
from django import forms
class CountryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'region': forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'get_subregion_for_region(this.value);'})
        }

class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....

    form = CountryForm

    class Media:
        js = (
            'geo_location/js/chained-region.js',
        )
```

And last added the URL pattern in the application urls.py file.
**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'geo_location'
urlpatterns = [
    path('get-subregions-for-region/', views.subregion_for_region, name='subregions-for-region'),
]
```